# Best way to replace multiple FOR loops with stream api in Java

Tags: java, performance, loops, java-stream

I want to make this function run is less time. I am assuming `stream()` might help. But not sure how.

```
private List<TodayMenu> getRecommendedTodayMenuItems(Map<String, Integer> itemsGroupedDailySales, List<TodayMenu> itemsOnTodayMenu) {

    List<TodayMenu> recommendedTodayMenu = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> itemGroupedDailySales : itemsGroupedDailySales.entrySet()) {
        for (TodayMenu todayMenu : itemsOnTodayMenu) {
            if (todayMenu.getMenuId().equals(itemGroupedDailySales.getKey())) {
                recommendedTodayMenu.add(todayMenu);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (recommendedTodayMenu.size() >= 9) {
            return recommendedTodayMenu;
        }
    }
    return recommendedTodayMenu;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result contains only records of itemsOnTodayMenu so you can start iterating over this list and perform a lookup in itemsGroupedDailySales (HashMap is good in this).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

private List<TodayMenu> getRecommendedTodayMenuItemsBetter(Map<String, Integer> itemsGroupedDailySales,
        List<TodayMenu> itemsOnTodayMenu) {
    return itemsOnTodayMenu.stream()
        .filter((tm)->itemsGroupedDailySales.containsKey(tm.getMenuId()))
        .limit(9)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

one remark: you don't use the values of itemsGroupedDailySales. Your logic stops after the first 9 matching items but there is no order defined. It is for example not the top most sold that are selected as recommended. I hope you are aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

You should index your itemsOnTodayMenu by id in a map. You can save time from O(n*m) to O(n+m).

- iterate itemsOnTodayMenu to build the map
- iterate itemsGroupedDailySales

  - get today menu by id from the map

Answer (score 0):

You intend to find a single element at most in the inner cycle from the outer cycle. So you need to [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) on the main structure, use [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) to check the equals that you had and call [findFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) to achieve the behavior with the `break` of your initial code. To [limit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-) the number of results, call the method with the same name.

I would write some code for this, but I am not experienced with Java stream and do not have the means to test whatever code I would write. So, please try implementing this idea and make sure to tell me how it goes.